# How to open a webpage in a site without appending html ?

Tags: php, web

I want to open a webpage in web-browser

```
www.somesite.com/myPage.html
```

I've created myPage.html by myself, plain html

I want to open this page via

```
www.somesite.com/myPage
```

I've placed `myPage.html` in `public_html` folder in my `cpanel`

Comment: do you use framework? (codeigniter, cakephp, etc?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option1**

Keep your file `myPage.html` in `public_html`

you need to create a `.htaccess` in `public_html` and add this into the file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

**Option 2**

1. Make a folder calls `myPage`
2. Rename file `myPage.html` to `index.html`
3. Movethe file `index.html` to `myPage` folder

**Note:-** Don't use both methods at once. Remove all the data from `.htacess` file before using `Option 2`

Comment: I tried option 2 but i'm getting "You don't have permission to access /support/.html on this server." I also tried by changing permission of index.html. but it doesn't work.

Comment: www.nexogen.in/privacy

Comment: also change the permission on folder `privacy` to 755

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nz72kfbrcyv3cx6/Screenshot%202015-02-24%2012.16.04.png?dl=0

Comment: still getting no where, change the privacy to 755 and also index.html to 755

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71553/discussion-between-lea-tano-and-whitefang).